# Redis Node – close all connections

Tags: node.js, redis

Is there any command or library in Node that would help me close all of the Redis connections?

I know I can track my connections and try to quit them inside `process.on('exit', ...)`, yet I'd like to have a fallback method that closes all the connections first, before initiating new ones.

Comment: When your application starts, then it shouldn't have any connection to your Redáis server. Or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza We're running an app on Heroku and when somebody e.g. changes an env var, the server restarts. Our current setup with Redis and Bull needs ~12 connections to Redis, and our current free development plan supports up to 20 connections at once. We started seeing errors about too many connections and were wondering if those 12 connections between restarts do not become 24 for some time.